# Unable to use model in migration in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, database, migration, yii, data-migration

Using migration to insert or change the table structure is no problem for me. But, I have a problems to to change the data inside a table using model. My idea is to do something like that:

```
public function up()
{
    $models = MyModel::model()->findAll();
    foreach ($models as $variable) {
        $variable->property = str_replace('.', ',', $variable->property);
        $variable->save();
    } 
}
```

It seems, that I'm unable to import the model, because I'm getting follwoing error:

```
*** applying m111010_084827_convert_point_2_comma
PHP Error[2]: include(MyModel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

If I try to import the Model before:

```
$modelClass = Yii::import('application.models.*');
```

then the error is:

```
*** applying m111010_084827_convert_point_2_comma
exception 'CDbException' with message 'The table "{{mymodel}}" for active record class "MyModel" cannot be found in the database.' in C:\...\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php:2276
```

Where is the problem? What am I doingwrong? How should I import model in migration inthe right way? Or maybe I should replace the strings with SQL commands?

Comment: This may seem like an obvious question but... do you have the proper CACtiveRecord model set up, does it specify the correct `tableName()`, and does the table exist in the database? Because I just did a quick test looping through some models in a migration it seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: @thaddeusmt: tableName, Models and Tables were right. but i never realized that in config/console.php is another db-configuration. after i changed that - it worked! thanks..

Comment: Ah! Yeah, that's a tricky one. Glad you got it figured out! I have a "base" config file I use for the DB info, and then I use CMap::mergeArray to combine it with my web and console config files so they inherit the same DB info.

Answer (score 5):

Migrations are definitely meant to be a set of SQL commands. I would recommend using a SELECT REPLACE command. See http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-replace.html

However, the approach you are taking should also work, as long as you include all the required php files. You might need your base models also:

```
   Yii::import('application.models.*');
   Yii::import('application.models.base.*');
```

And make sure you edit config/console.php to have the correct database information.